# How to iterate through JSON data in PHP for Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am building a plugin that calls a 3rd party API. I am getting data back but it looks a little funky and I am unable to iterate and manipulate the data to display on my page.

I am using this function to call the API which is working...

```
function herocreative_rentcafe_get_data( $herocreative_companycode, $herocreative_propertycode ) {

    $json_feed_url = 'https://api.rentcafe.com/rentcafeapi.aspx?requestType=floorplan&companyCode=' . $herocreative_companycode . '&propertyCode=' . $herocreative_propertycode ;
    $args = array( 'timeout' => 120 );

    $json_feed = wp_remote_get( $json_feed_url, $args );

    $herocreative_data = json_decode( $json_feed['body'] );

    return $herocreative_data;

}
```

I am using this code to iterate the response...

```
   <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count($herocreative_data); $i++ ): ?>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <?php echo $herocreative_data->{'AvailableUnitsCount'}[$i]; ?>              
            </li>
        </ul>                                   
    </li>                               
    <?php endfor; ?>
```

The data that is coming back is this:

JSON Feed

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#321 (18) {
    ["PropertyId"]=>
    string(6) "457547"
    ["FloorplanId"]=>
    string(7) "2027167"
    ["FloorplanName"]=>
    string(11) "One Bedroom"
    ["Beds"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Baths"]=>
    string(4) "1.00"
    ["MinimumSQFT"]=>
    string(3) "714"
    ["MaximumSQFT"]=>
    string(3) "714"
    ["MinimumRent"]=>
    string(4) "1125"
    ["MaximumRent"]=>
    string(4) "1355"
    ["MinimumDeposit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["MaximumDeposit"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["AvailableUnitsCount"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["AvailabilityURL"]=>
    string(137) "https://epicasset.securecafe.com/onlineleasing/park-210/oleapplication.aspx?stepname=Apartments&myOlePropertyId=457547&floorPlans=2027167"
    ["FloorplanImageURL"]=>
    string(65) "http://cdn.rentcafe.com/dmslivecafe/3/457547/3_457547_2310392.jpg"
    ["FloorplanImageName"]=>
    string(7) "1x1.jpg"
    ["PropertyShowsSpecials"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["FloorplanHasSpecials"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["UnitTypeMapping"]=>
    string(6) "p0.1x1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#323 (18) {
    ["PropertyId"]=>
    string(6) "457547"
    ["FloorplanId"]=>
    string(7) "2027168"
    ["FloorplanName"]=>
    string(20) "Two Bedroom One Bath"
    ["Beds"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Baths"]=>
    string(4) "1.00"
    ["MinimumSQFT"]=>
    string(4) "1000"
    ["MaximumSQFT"]=>
    string(4) "1000"
    ["MinimumRent"]=>
    string(4) "1325"
    ["MaximumRent"]=>
    string(4) "1455"
    ["MinimumDeposit"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["MaximumDeposit"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AvailableUnitsCount"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AvailabilityURL"]=>
    string(137) "https://epicasset.securecafe.com/onlineleasing/park-210/oleapplication.aspx?stepname=Apartments&myOlePropertyId=457547&floorPlans=2027168"
    ["FloorplanImageURL"]=>
    string(65) "http://cdn.rentcafe.com/dmslivecafe/3/457547/3_457547_2310393.jpg"
    ["FloorplanImageName"]=>
    string(7) "2x1.jpg"
    ["PropertyShowsSpecials"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["FloorplanHasSpecials"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["UnitTypeMapping"]=>
    string(6) "p0.2x1"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#324 (18) {
    ["PropertyId"]=>
    string(6) "457547"
    ["FloorplanId"]=>
    string(7) "2027169"
    ["FloorplanName"]=>
    string(20) "Two Bedroom Two Bath"
    ["Beds"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Baths"]=>
    string(4) "2.00"
    ["MinimumSQFT"]=>
    string(4) "1095"
    ["MaximumSQFT"]=>
    string(4) "1095"
    ["MinimumRent"]=>
    string(4) "1395"
    ["MaximumRent"]=>
    string(4) "1525"
    ["MinimumDeposit"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["MaximumDeposit"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AvailableUnitsCount"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AvailabilityURL"]=>
    string(137) "https://epicasset.securecafe.com/onlineleasing/park-210/oleapplication.aspx?stepname=Apartments&myOlePropertyId=457547&floorPlans=2027169"
    ["FloorplanImageURL"]=>
    string(65) "http://cdn.rentcafe.com/dmslivecafe/3/457547/3_457547_2310394.jpg"
    ["FloorplanImageName"]=>
    string(7) "2x2.jpg"
    ["PropertyShowsSpecials"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["FloorplanHasSpecials"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["UnitTypeMapping"]=>
    string(6) "p0.2x2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is foreach loop over the array and then as each occurance contains an object address it as such

```
<?php 
foreach ( $herocreative_data as $data) : 
?>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php echo $data->AvailableUnitsCount; ?>              
        </li>
    </ul>                                   
</li>                               
<?php 
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! I am new to PHP and didn't realize it was something so easy! You are a life saver. Thanks for your time and answer.